# In OOP, when writing a subclass are you meant to change the original main method code? What instead?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, encryption

I know that the whole point of OOP is so that code doesnt have to be rewritten.

I have a class (lets call it E) and a main class (lets call it main) with a main method that validates some inputs and then feeds them into class E (which encrypts the inpts) to get a result to output to the user (the encrypted input).

Now I am writing a subclass from the perspective that I was someone else improving the program. I have a subclass of the encryption class which uses similar principles but an improved method of encryption (lets call it class ImprovedE).

As the new developer I am pretending to be, would I just write the subclass and then rewrite the main method from the original program to feed the inputs into Improved E instead of E?

I know I can't override the main method but I dont think I should be changing the original code either. Any help would be appreaciated.

Heres the code (EDIT), that i forgot to add.

```
package encryption;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static encryption.encryptionChoice.*;

public class main {

//These are all the reusable variables created to temporarily store information before pushing it to the Encryption class

//This is a simple starter message to inform the user of how to use the program
private String initialDisplayInformation = "Message Encryption/Decryption program for use with letters and spaces only. \nPress any key to continue...";

//These are the "scope" input and output variables visible to the user
private String inputString;
private String outputString;
//This creates the encryption class
private Encryption myEncryption = new Encryption();
//These are used to later create two loops that only break when an acceptable input has been input for the values
private Boolean inputValidated = false;
private Boolean cypherValidated = false;
private Boolean choiceValidated = false;

private void initialInfo() {
    //These 2 lines make the user have to hit any key before continuing after reading the info
    System.out.println(initialDisplayInformation);
    String pressAnyKey = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}

private void inputValidation(){    
    //This loop attepts to validate the message input and uses the boolean returned fromthe Encryption.setInput class to see the success
    //It prints a detailed error and repeats if unsuccessful
    do {
        System.out.println("\nEnter your message: "); 
        try {
            inputValidated = myEncryption.setInput(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        } catch(NotACharacterException e) {
            System.out.println(e.errorMessage());
        }
    } while(!inputValidated); 
}

private void cypherValidation(){
    //This repeats the exact process as the previous loop, but for the cypher length
    do {
        System.out.println("\nEnter your cypher length (How much the message will be/was offset by: ");  
        try {
            cypherValidated = myEncryption.setCypher(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
            if(!cypherValidated) {
                System.out.println("That is not an acceptable integer, please try again... ");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("That is not a valid input, please try again... ");
        }

    } while(!cypherValidated);
}

private void encryptionDecision(){
    do {
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to 1)Encrypt 2)Decrypt the message: ");  
        String choiceString = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        encryptionChoice choice = ERROR;

        if(choiceString.equalsIgnoreCase("Encrypt")|| choiceString.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            choice = ENCRYPT;
        }


        if(choiceString.equalsIgnoreCase("Decrypt") || choiceString.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            choice = DECRYPT;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(myEncryption.getInput());
            System.out.println(myEncryption.EncryptionDecryption(choice));
            choiceValidated = true;

        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Please only enter: Encrypt, Decrypt, 1 or 2. Please try again... ");
        }
    } while(!choiceValidated);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean runProgram = true;
    while(runProgram){
        main thread = new main();
        thread.initialInfo();
        thread.inputValidation();
        thread.cypherValidation();
        thread.encryptionDecision();

        runProgram=false;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nPress 'r' to restart or 'enter' to exit");
         if(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().equals("r")) {
            runProgram=true;
         }
    }
}
```

}

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
package encryption;

 /**
 *
  * @author Alex
 */
public class SingleKeywordEncryption extends Encryption {
protected String keywordString;

protected Integer getKeywordCypher(String keyword, Integer term){
    Character letterInKeyword = 0;
    Integer cypherLength;

    if(term<keyword.length()){
        letterInKeyword = keyword.charAt(term);
    }
    else if(term>=keyword.length()) {
        letterInKeyword = keyword.charAt(term%keyword.length());
    }


    cypherLength = termOf(letterInKeyword);
    return cypherLength;
}

@Override
public String EncryptionDecryption(encryptionChoice choice) {
    String outputString = "";

    switch(choice){
        case ENCRYPT:
            for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++) {
                outputString = outputString + letterOf(termOf(inputString.charAt(i)) + getKeywordCypher(keywordString, i)); 

            }
            break;

        case DECRYPT:
            for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++) {
                outputString = outputString + letterOf(termOf(inputString.charAt(i)) - getKeywordCypher(keywordString, i)); 
            }
            break;   
        default:
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();


    };
        return outputString;
}
```

}

```
     package encryption;//Includes the class int he encryption package of classes     for my project
//This creates a class called Encryption where the majority of my project is      stored
 public class Encryption {
     //These create the variables needed throughout the class
    //This is final so that it is immutable and usable in all the methods
     //I made it a Character array to save memory use and to allow simpler comparison methods in other areas of the program
    private final Character[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
     //These are private for good coding practice, so that they can only be modified from within the class
     private Integer cypher;
     protected String inputString;


public String getInput() {
    return inputString;
}

//This class simply validates and saves the cypher length to its variable and returns a boolean of its success
public boolean setCypher(Integer cypherToAdd) {
    while(cypherToAdd>26 || cypherToAdd<0){
        return false;
    }
//It tries to save it and returns false if it cannot be saved as an integer
    try {
        cypher = cypherToAdd;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//This class validates andsaves the input to its variable and removes any whitespace from it
public boolean setInput(String inputToAdd) throws NotACharacterException {
    //This uses replaceAll to remove whitespace and saves the object that is rejurned from the method to String input
    String input = inputToAdd.replaceAll("\\s","");
    //This iterates through every character in the input and checks that it is a letter
    for (int term=0; term<input.length();term++) {
        //If a term is not a letter, it throws the custom NotACharacterException and passes information of which non-letter character caused it
        if(!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(term))){
            throw new NotACharacterException("'" + String.valueOf(input.charAt(term)) + "' This character can not be used in this program...\nStick to letters and spaces only please."); 
        }
    }
    inputString = input;
    return true;
}

//This class returns the term of a passed letter in the alphabet
protected int termOf(Character letter) {
    //The term variable to be returned is initialised immediately
    int term =0;

    //The for loop iterates through every letter in the alphabet and compares it with the letter passed to the method to find its term
    for (int currentTerm=0; currentTerm<alphabet.length;currentTerm++) {
        //When the letters match, the term is returned to where the method is called
        if(letter.toLowerCase(letter)==alphabet[currentTerm]){
            term = currentTerm;
        }
    }
    return term;
}

//This class returns the letter of a passed term in the alphabet
protected Character letterOf(int inputTerm) { 

    if(inputTerm>25){
        return alphabet[inputTerm-26];
    } else if (inputTerm<0) {
        return alphabet[inputTerm+26];
    }
    else {
    //It recieves the character by gathering the character in the inputTerm's place in the array, and returns it
    return alphabet[inputTerm];
    }
}

public String EncryptionDecryption(encryptionChoice choice){
    String outputString = "";

    switch(choice){
        case ENCRYPT:
            for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++) {
                outputString = outputString + letterOf(termOf(inputString.charAt(i))+ cypher); 
            }
            break;

        case DECRYPT:
            for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++) {
                outputString = outputString + letterOf(termOf(inputString.charAt(i))- cypher); 
            }
            break;   
        default:
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();


    };
        return outputString;
}
```

}

Comment: I may have answered my own question here, i just realised my main method doesnt directly call the E class, it just calls a method in the main class which caslls the E class. Am I right in suggesting I should just change this method in the E class to just point to the improved E class instead. So in my code - change the EncryptionDecryptionDecision method to get the output from the singleKeyEncryption instead of the EnryptionDecryption class? (By overriding the EncryptioNDecryptionDecision method that is of course, not chanignt eh original code) Am i right?

Comment: 'I know that the whole point of OOP is so that code doesnt have to be rewritten...'
Actually, the purpose of OOP is to make the organization of code easier to conceptualize. `extends` is considered by many to be an [antipattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html).

Comment: Your main program (which should ***not*** be called "main") should only deal with getting the input and writing the output, and hand off _everything_ to do with the encryption to an _"Encryptor"_ — which should probably be an `interface` not a class. Then you have two implementations of the Encryptor interface; your initial simple `public class Encryption implements Encryptor` and your improved `public class ImprovedEncryption implements Encryptor` .... the improved class _does not extend_ the original, unless it is going to actually re-use (not replace) some of the original's methods.

Comment: The only methods I would want to resuse from the Encryptor class would be the setting and getting the input variable, and the termof() and letterOf() methods that easily find the realtive term or letter in the alphabet. If i used implements, would these still be reusable?

Comment: You are looking for *Dependency Injection* also known as *Inversion of Control*.

Comment: If `ImprovedE` is really an improvement to `E` it should probably override just one or two methods of `E`, re-using _termOf()_ etc., but in any case you should have _at least_ 3 files — `MyProgram.java` (which has the "main" method), `E.java`, and `ImprovedE.java` (and more if using an interface and base class) and get all of the I/O out of the encryption classes and into the main program. Pass the plain-text and key as _parameters_ to the encryption, and receive the cipher-text as the return value.

Comment: Would this program plan work-------                                                   Abstract base encryptor class – has termOf,letterOf classes (manipulating the alphabet), getinput, set input,  and then defines encryptionmethod method
Original encryptionclass – has its own encryption method, implements the rest
New improvedencryption class – has its own encryption method, implements the rest
ProgramInit – collects and validates the inputs from the user to be sent to one of the encryption classes
Main – calls programinit

Comment: Edit that plan - instead of having get input and set input classes, just have parameters of the base encryptor class that set themselves in a constructor method?

Comment: Don’t use boxed values like `Boolean`, `Integer` or `Character` when you never intent them to be *nullable*. Just use `boolean`, `int` and `char`. It might improve the performance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, you will have to change something somewhere in your code so that the main uses your ImprovedE class instead of the E class. Otherwise, the program will not know by itself if you want to use E or ImprovedE.

If you will not use the encryption method in E and will always use ImprovedE, it would be better to include all the methods from E into ImprovedE. This way, you will not have to make any decisions on which class to use.

If you still want to be able to switch between the two classes, I recommend using the [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. You would put any methods shared between the two classes (such as `termOf(Character letter)`, `letterOf(int inputTerm)` and `setInput(String inputToAdd)`) in a class accessible by both encyption strategy, and you would have two ConcreteStrategy: E and ImprovedE.

This way, you can switch between the two strategies quickly, just by changing the ConcreteStrategy (In your case, if you want to use the old or the new encryption method). You could also prompt the user to know which encryption method he wants if that's a valid use case.

Comment: As improvedE shares many of the classes as E, I have made coded that improvedE extends E and then overrided the method in it that changes it. As the "new developer" i am, I only want to use improvedE from now on (be with that improved E inherits some of its methods from E). Is it OOP acceptable to just change the original code of the main method? or would a new deveoper in that situation not have access to that?

Comment: The fact that ImprovedE extends E is a good theoretical example. It is true that the definition of E can be applied to ImprovedE. However, in reality, you do not usually extend a class just to make improvements to it. You extend it because you still need both to exist separately. Otherwise, you would have a huge tree of classes that simply contains a small improvements.

Comment: So if the plan was just to make this one new way of encrypting would it be better to implement the original method in the new class, instead of extending it and changing the original main method code.

Comment: @AlexGower - Perhaps both `E` and `ImprovedE` should _both_ extend `public abstract class AbstractBaseEncryption` which would declare some abstract methods and also implement common and/or "default" methods that all-or-at-least-many encryption implementations would need/use.  This organization would enable the Strategy pattern that Cydrick mentions.

Comment: Side little question, in well written OOP code, is the original main method code allowed to be changed when changing the program, or are subclasses of the original program the only ways that it should be changed. (Its a simple question that would help alot thanks)

Comment: @StephenP This would work too. Even if it is not strictly the "Strategy" pattern (since the Strategy class should be an interface), it is another possible variation worth considering if OP would still desire the separation in both encryption classes.

Comment: @AlexGower Usually you never change the main method. The main class calls another class (lets call it ProgramInit), and you modify ProgramInit according to your needs.

Comment: So the plan of the code should be: abstract base class with the basic get,set, termof, letterof classes coded in there (along with the definition of an "encryptionMethod" method that will change per subclass. Then the original encryption class will just implement that with its own encryptionMethod class, and the new improved encryption class will still jsut implement the abstract class but with its own encryptionMethod class?

Comment: and then instead of having the not-OOP method of changing what the main method calls when upgrading from the original encryption method to the improved encryption method, I would have another small class called programInit which is always called by the main method. But is it good OOP to just change the orinial code in this ProgramInit class? Because if i override something in it in a subclass that would mean changing the main method to run the subclass of programinit so that would be bad. ?

Comment: Here are the options: 


Option 1: You do not want to use E, and only ImprovedE:


You put all your changes from ImprovedE in E and remove any unuseful code from E. This includes the `EncryptionDecryption` method located in E. You make a `ProgramInit` class with a `start` method. You initialize `ProgramInit` and call that `start` method from your `main` method. In `start`, you do what was previously in your `main` method.

Comment: Option 2: You still want to have E and ImprovedE seperatly because you need both: You create a class called `AbstractE` which contains `termof`, `letterof`, other common methods and `public abstract String EncryptionDecryption(encryptionChoice choice)` You create class E and ImprovedE which extends `AbstractE` and implement the `EncryptionDecryption` method. You also make a `ProgramInit` class with a `start` method. You initialize `ProgramInit` and call that `start` method from your `main` method. In `start`, you either create a ImprovedE or E class, and do your manipulations on it.

Comment: Again, it is not common practice to extend a class simply to do some modifications/improvements to your code. You generally extend a class because you still need both. If you don't need both, use Option 1. If you still need both, use Option 2. Note that it is okay to modify your original code (the main or the `ProgramInit` class) as long as the modification is as small as changing the name of a class.

Comment: Thanks. So if that had been done with just the E class originally (with a ProgramInit method calling it). As the "new developer" the OOP way of doing it would be to create a subclass of the abstract class with a better EncryptionDecryption method and then edit the ProgramInit class's original code? Basically is the editing the programinit original code the OOP way of doing it (just checking) thanks

Comment: Oh so small changes are OK with OOP, its just directly editing an original class which OOP would rather you made a subclass instead. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. You're only changing from E to ImprovedE. The `AbstractE` class and the abstract method guarantees that no other modifications to the code will be necessary.

Comment: Also am I right in saying that Option 1 is good for now, but Option 2 is a much more OOP way which will facilitate further improvements in the future better?  And am I also right in saying that if only the improved encryption method is meant to be used after each change, OOP would want you to just replace the original encryption method not make a sub class, but if you wanted a setup of trialing many encryption methods OOP would want you to have many subclasses which can be used individually?

Comment: Yes and yes. It is nice to future-proof by making subclasses, but it makes your code harder to read and follow. If you don't need another class, you do not share methods across many classes and and it does not make your code easier to read, you usually don't create new classes.

Comment: Thank you very much, so for me as this work is going to be assessed I will say that stage 1 is abstract class with orignal encryption class being called by program init (being called by main). ANd that a "new developer came along" who just created an improved encryption class that still implements the base class and then changed program init to have a user input to choose which type of encryption they wanted. And then finally that a 3rd new developer came along and made a new improved subclass that implements the base class as usual and simply changed program init to make a user selection of 3

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the whole point of OOP is so that code doesnt have to be rewritten...

Actually, the purpose of OOP is to make the organization of code easier to conceptualize. `extends` is considered by many to be an [antipattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html).

Consider using `implements` on an abstract base class to define an interface and letting future devs worry about 'improvements'.

Comment: WIth implements, can I still inherit basic methods such as termOf and letterOf and getInput() and setInput() in all subclasses I use?

Comment: That article is pretty bogus. His "losing flexibility" statement has nothing to do with classes, rather than violating dependency inversion. His "fragile base" arises from violating liskov subsitution. Interfaces cannot replace classes. Also note the comment on it, stating "this article should be removed". They are both their own tool. You could see it as interfaces abstract behavior while classes may help abstract state

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `main` method is static, which means it cannot be overriden. This is by design, but not necessarily optimal design. There is no universal reason why this could not be done in principle, but Java does not do it.

The thing is: you should not have to need this in the first place. Your former developer mixed responsabilities by putting all of these encryption methods and state information in the same class which represents the computation itself: your `main` class.

So, what you have to do is actually decouple these things because the main method has to very small and narrow-purposed. When this happens, it will not feel like there is so much repetition in place. If there is, there is always more room for refactoring.